# Referencing an inherited method at compile time in python

Tags: python, inheritance, function-pointers

I have a `Specialized` class that inherits a `@classmethod` from a `Generic` class and maps some strings to methods:

```
class Generic(object):

    @classmethod
    def generate_static_data(cls):
        return cls.field.upper()


class Specialized(Generic):

    field = 'Some data'

    MAPPING = {
        # NameError: name 'Specialized' is not defined
        'key': Specialized.generate_static_data,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        for key, meth in Specialized.MAPPING.iteritems():
            print(key, meth())
```

How do I reference the inherited method?

- I cannot reference it via the `Specialized` class name (probably because the class hasn't been completely parsed, yet?): `# NameError: name 'Specialized' is not defined`,
- and I cannot reference it without the class name as with a "local" method: `NameError: name 'generate_static_data' is not defined`.
- If I reference it via the `Generic` class, the `cls` parameter points to the wrong class.

*Edit:* One might obviously encode the reference as a string and only expand it at runtime, but I feel that's unnecessarily complicated:

```
MAPPING = {
    'key': 'generate_static_data',
}

def __init__(self):
    for key, meth in Specialized.MAPPING.iteritems():
        print(key, getattr(Specialized, meth)())
```

In addition, in the real world project this example comes from, mapping strings to strings is the default, and I really like the distinction of mapping some strings to callables in contrast to mapping to another string that just happens to be resolvable into a callable.

Comment: Have you tried creating such mapping in the Specialized constructor?

Comment: Uh, that would mean the mapping would be available on the class only after at least one instance has been created? That sounds like it might cause some unpleasant surprises ;)

Comment: Indeed you are correct :)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1

The simplest way I know of to achieve this is this:

```
class Generic(object):

    @classmethod
    def generate_static_data(cls):
        return cls.field.upper()


class Specialized(Generic):

    field = 'Some data'    

    def __init__(self):
        for key, meth in Specialized.MAPPING.iteritems():
            print(key, meth())

Specialized.MAPPING = {
    'key': Specialized.generate_static_data,
}
```

Basically, this defines `Specialized.MAPPING` *after* `Specialized` is defined, so you don't run into the `NameError: name 'Specialized' is not defined` issue:

```
>>> Specialized()
('key', 'SOME DATA')
<__main__.Specialized object at 0x1049e9d50>
```

### Solution 2

One other way of doing this is using the `getattr` function and referring to the method name `"generate_static_data"` instead of the method object itself in the mapping. Note that this particular implementation will only work if all of the values in `MAPPING` are class methods on `Specialized` (inherited or otherwise):

```
class Generic(object):

    @classmethod
    def generate_static_data(cls):
        return cls.field.upper()


class Specialized(Generic):

    field = 'Some data'    

    MAPPING = {
        'key': 'generate_static_data',
    }

    def __init__(self):
        for key, meth in Specialized.MAPPING.iteritems():
            print(key, getattr(Specialized, meth)())
```

This results in the same output:

```
>>> Specialized()
('key', 'SOME DATA')
<__main__.Specialized object at 0x1065a2cd0>
```

Personally, I think the first solution is cleaner, but the second solution keeps everything defined within the `Specialized` class.